# CLR, Win32, WinRT in Windows architecture

Tags: .net, winapi, architecture, windows-runtime, clr

I have browsed around and found similar questions to which all responses have been unclear and blurry at best and it annoys me to not have a clear picture of the Windows architecture. There are layers in Windows which in my head has always looked something like this (from top to bottom):

[.NET]

[Win32]

[Microkernel]

[HAL]

[Hardware]

Recently I have seen images like this:
[image]
[image]

I am confused, especially about the fact that it seems that CLR is running in parallell with WinAPI. I guess my question is this:

**UPDATE**
Q: Where can I find clear and explanatory **resources** that describe the OS architecture in recent versions of Windows (7,8, Server 2012 etc)?

Comment: You are never going to get any insight from staring at these kind of block diagrams.  Windows architecture fills many books.  Best to get started with Rossinovich' Windows Internals 5th edition, it is excellent.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will definitely try and find it.

Comment: @HansPassant You say "Best to get started" - How much prerequisite knowledge of the .NET platform and operating system internals would you say one should have before reading Windows' Internals, in your opinion?

Comment: '...specially about the fact that it seems that CLR is running in parallell with WinAPI'. CLR uses Windows API when interpreting the intermediate code to perform dynamic linking of functions / I/O tasks required by the code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'll assume this question is about WinRT, it is otherwise entirely too vague to answer.

The diagram at the bottom is very misleading.  It shows the point of view from what you need to know as a programmer.  And if you create a WinRT app then the olden winapi is not something you ever deal with directly.  It was *replaced* by the WinRT api and you are only supposed to use it to obtain operating system services.

The implementation is very different.  The CLR still very much runs on top of the winapi, just like it does in a desktop app.  And it interoperates with unmanaged code, Windows is fundamentally an unmanaged operating system.  Also the case for WinRT, it is an unmanaged api that's based on COM.

Every WinRT app is in reality an out-of-process COM server, much like such servers were used 30 years ago.  It does run in a special mode, Microsoft added an extra layer to the plumbing that makes UAC work.  It is called the "app container", it works like a sandbox.  Just like UAC prevents a program from accessing certain directories or registry keys if the user didn't get elevated by a UAC prompt, the app container prevents a program from using winapi functions that are troublesome.  The kind that creates usability or security problems or drain a battery too fast.  WinRT has *replacements* for such winapi functions.

COM is a bit notorious, it is the universal interop solution used by Microsoft but it is not particularly easy to program.  Microsoft did a *lot* of work to make COM more usable, mostly by completely hiding it.  Notable are that type libraries were replaced with .winmd files, a much enhanced version that can express a lot more details.  They used the data format for .NET metadata.

And a pivotal way they hid COM is the *language projection* built into various runtime support libraries.  For C++ it is hidden in the C++/CX language extensions and the runtime library.  For Javascript it is hidden inside the Chakra execution engine.  And for managed code it is hidden inside the .NET framework with [TypeForwardedTo] in the reference assemblies.  The language projection translates from WinRT types and behavior to types specific to the language.  Basic stuff, like a COM error code gets translated to an exception.  And the WinRT HSTRING type gets translated to System.String.  Etcetera.

There are a few places where the language projection peeks through the cracks, visible in oddly seeming restrictions.  Like a WinRT component must always be a sealed class, a side effect of COM not supporting implementation inheritance.  Or you can expose a DateTimeOffset in a component but not a DateTime.  And some WinRT types don't map well to .NET types, IBuffer is notorious.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately - phrases like "CLR still very much runs on top" and "special mode" gives me the chills. What does "pretty much" really mean, what is "special" ? I should rephrase my question to make it more obvious that I am looking for resources that explains the Window architecture rather then quick answers to these complex questions.

Comment: There's no way to stick a fork in this question that's going to make you happy.  You cannot expect SO users to write a book, you'll need to buy or borrow one.

Comment: So, do you have any suggestion on which one I should buy or borrow?

Comment: You are a bit dense about it, I already gave you one.  You should read all of them.  Where to start is impossible to guess, aim low.  When to stop because you think you know enough is up to you.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping for something more condensed with focus on the technology stack but I guess I would have to dive deeper and try to sort out the noise by myself. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 4):

WinRT is primarily a set of APIs to build Metro apps for all Metro-supported platforms (including for Windows 8 for ARM). The Windows Runtime provides a large set of new APIs to Windows Experience developers.

From http://arstechnica.com/features/2012/10/windows-8-and-winrt-everything-old-is-new-again/5/:

> The WinRT name stands for "Windows Runtime." However, this **isn't a
>   runtime in the same way** that Microsoft's .NET Runtime was a runtime,
>   or the way Oracle's Java Runtime Environment is a runtime. In the .NET
>   and Java cases, the runtime is a relatively large software component
>   that provides a virtual machine environment, garbage-collected memory,
>   various kinds of code safety verification, and more. The .NET and Java
>   runtimes are intimately involved in virtually everything a .NET or
>   Java program does, providing extensive infrastructure to software
>   developers.
>
> WinRT offers nothing quite like those runtimes. **WinRT is a set of
>   software libraries that provides an API offering a range of
>   services—graphics, networking, storage, printing.** In addition to this,
>   there is a relatively small infrastructural component.

When you develop a metro style app, the .NET Framework and the Common Language Runtime (CLR) are integrated with the WinRT. The CLR 4.5, which ships as part of the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 in Windows 8, **enables developers writing managed code to use the Windows Runtime APIs in a natural way** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh694558.aspx). WinRT is not available in Windows 7 or previous version of windows.

There is an **awesome article** at http://arstechnica.com/features/2012/10/windows-8-and-winrt-everything-old-is-new-again/ ....**in 7 parts** it describes **in deep with history** from COM > .NET > WinRT. To jump into WinRT look into [5th part of it](http://arstechnica.com/features/2012/10/windows-8-and-winrt-everything-old-is-new-again/5/).

Hope it will clarify your doubts. Please let me know in case of further questions.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "top of the OS" - everything accept hardware is on "top of the OS". WinRT is on top of Win32 as far as I know. I don´t recognize that CLR is a sub platform of WinRT. Rather, I am under the impression that WinRT is located on top of Win32 as an individual framework and may(!) use .NET through language projections (somehow?) but that is optional since it might use other languages such as unmanaged C++. Thank you for your answer but it actually made me even more confused :O

Comment: By saying "top of the OS", means adjacent top to above the OS that is Win32. It exposes Win32 to virtually any programming language through what are called language projections. I have edited the answers to avoid further confusions..Please go through the article at http://arstechnica.com/features/2012/10/windows-8-and-winrt-everything-old-is-new-again/ ....then your doubts would be clear... and sorry..the story is big and complex and can not be told in few words...so please bear !!

Comment: Yeah, I realize the complexity of the question. That is why the question was - where can I find the answers rather then, provide me with the answer :) Anyway, thank you for your response!

Comment: Most welcome dear...I have modifies some content in my answer above...Hope it's for better... I really appreciate your queries and quest to have crisp knowledge. Thanks.